# Migrate Web Application from Kendo UI to React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, kendo-ui

What are the consequences of migration of the front front with *HTML5, CSS3, JS, jQuery, Kendo UI* to *HTML5, CSS3, React* for a Schedule App

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too general. It depends how big is project. Your question can be shorten to rewriting Js/JQuery to React. There are many aspects and answers to this question - it really depends who is answering.

From developer point of view you have plenty of reasons to move to ReactJs. You can google many tutorials why ReactJS is smarter choice than JQuery.

Comment: thank you, but can we use React in  Schedule App ? like KendoUI?